# When table reach max-height, continue column next to the first one

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have a table who contains text from mysql. The script looks like this:

```
<table>
<?php
$check_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DBtable");

while ($check_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_sql))
{
$one = $check_row['contOne'];
$two = $check_row['contTwo'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $one . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $st .  "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

The table works fine, but I want the table to continue next side by side each other instead of me have to scroll down on my page to see the rest.

Comment: I think scrolling to the side to see more is worse than scrolling down

Comment: That's not the problem.

Comment: This won't be easy because every screen height will be different, so you'll probably need to use an Ajax call on page load that posts screen resolution to this script in order for php to dynamically determine max number of rows.

Comment: The page I making is just for me and my screen so I don't think i actually have to carry about that in this particularly code.

Comment: But, maybe it's easier to use <li> instead of <table>?

Comment: Then edit your question to include the required screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Even scrolling horizontally is not a good solution, you should not display all the data at once(what if you have thousands or millions of rows). The best solution for this situation the **paging**.
You can take a look at this tutorial 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm